# How Can I Search on A Treeset to Find Values that Are Either Greater or Less Than or Case Insensitive?

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I am trying out creating an in-memory database solution. Either `HashMap` or `TreeSet`. I know how I can search for a value using contains, and if this was a normal database situation this would be easier. But if I'm trying to search for a value by case-insensitive or a numerical value that is either greater or less than, how would I go about that in this case?

Here is my last name method, but it is just a simple contains, if it is is case insensitive it's not found

```
case 4:
    Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Search Last Name ");
    String retLn = input4.nextLine();

    if(employeeKey.containsKey(retLn))
    {
          EmpManager searchedEmp = employeeKey.get(retLn);
          System.out.println(searchedEmp);
          System.out.println("");
    }

    else
    {
          System.out.println("No Last Name Found");
          System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: use Treeset.higher, .lower, .ceiling, or .floor.  Use all lower case keys to make it case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `TreeMap` with Custom `Comparator`.

When you want a case-insensitive comparison:

```
new TreeMap<String,V>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

When you want an Integer based comparison:

```
new TreeMap<Integer,V>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Or just use default comparator:

```
new TreeMap<Integer,V>();
```

For finding all entries greater or lesser than a value use `headMap(), tailMap() or subMap()`

Answer (score 0):

As per your current solution, just ensure whenever you're adding to the `Map` that you turn the *keys* to *lowerCase* to make it case-insensitive, which then makes it easier to compare against user input later on e.g.

```
if(employeeKey.containsKey(retLn.toLowerCase())) // considering the keys inside the map are all lowercase
```

if you later want to search based on some given range, then you could do this:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
     if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(retLn) && value > someValue && value < someValue){
           // access the value here
     }
});
```

Comment: OK, but what if for example. I'm adding a Integer, and later want to search based a greater/less than value?

Comment: this is only a partly solution though - one would have to ensure that employeeKey also only has lowerCase keys.

Comment: There values for the map, not keys.

Comment: @goerlibe I have mentioned that within my post. However, my second solution solves that.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `containsKey()` method in your `HashMap` definition.

For example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {     
  @Override
  public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    for (String s : this.keySet()) {
      String keyString = (String) key;
      if (keyString.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) 
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
};
```